Check Duplicate Data
I have this code that check duplicate and copy the data to another sheet.
I'm wondering if VBA could also write if it's duplicate number 1, 2, and so on based on which duplicate row is the first one. If it is possible I wish to write Duplicate 1, Duplicate 2, and so on in Column BK.
   'Cek Duplikat pindahin ke sheet tempcek (cek melihat ke email)
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, dupRng As Range, rowRng As Range
    Dim arrData, oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Const KEY_COL = "T" ' Col [Email]
    Const COL_CNT = 20 ' Col A to T
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("ALL")
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("tempcek")
    ' load data from sheet1
    With oSht1
        Set rngData = .Cells(1, KEY_COL).Resize(.Range(KEY_COL & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    arrData = rngData.Value
    If Not VBA.IsArray(arrData) Then
        MsgBox "No data is on Sheet1.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' load data into Dict
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, 1) = CStr(arrData(i, 1))
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        Set rowRng = oSht1.Cells(i, 1)
        If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
            If dupRng Is Nothing Then
                Set dupRng = Application.Union(rowRng, objDic(sKey))
            Else
                Set dupRng = Application.Union(dupRng, rowRng, objDic(sKey))
            End If
        Else
            Set objDic(sKey) = rowRng
        End If
    Next i
    If Not dupRng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print dupRng.Address
       dupRng.EntireRow.Copy oSht2.Range("A2")
    End If

This is the sample data (note: the column is not applicable to code provided above)

I wish the macro could read that bruce in row 2 is the duplicate 1 and bruce in row 7 is the duplicate 2 and so on.


Add snippet to populate BK.

Note: Untested code. If the output is not as your expected, pls share sample data.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example


Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    ' Your code
    If Not dupRng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print dupRng.Address
       dupRng.EntireRow.Copy oSht2.Range("A2")
    End If
    ' ====================
    ' ** New code
    Dim rngData2 As Range, arrKey
    Const FLAG_COL = "BK"
    Set rngData2 = oSht2.Range("A2:A" & oSht2.Range(KEY_COL & oSht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    ' Load data into array
    arrKey = rngData2.Columns(KEY_COL).Value
    objDic.RemoveAll
    For i = LBound(arrKey) To UBound(arrKey)
        sKey = arrKey(i, 1)
        If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) + 1
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = 1
        End If
        ' populate Col BK
        arrKey(i, 1) = "Duplicate " & objDic(sKey)
    Next
    rngData2.Columns(FLAG_COL).Value = arrKey
    ' ====================


Thank you for your help. I've tried to implement the code, but it doesn't give results that I want. Instead, for every same name the macro wrote Duplicate 2 to both of them. While, it should have be Duplicate 1 and 2. I've edit the question with the sample data. I hope it could help :)
